# How to render KendoUI column based on data

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to render customer html based on the column data. Say show "promotion image" if IsHavingPromotion = true.

Or render star rating image based on the value retrieved. How do i do it with KendoUI template?

```
        .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(r => r.Id).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(r => r.Name);
                    columns.Bound(r => r.GuestNumberMax).ClientTemplate("suitable for <strong>#= GuestNumberMax #</strong> pax");
                    columns.Bound(r => r.Description);
                    columns.Bound(r => r.IsHavingPromotion).ClientTemplate("# RenderIsHavingPromotion(this, IsHavingPromotion) #");
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*'Or render star rating image based on the value retrieved'* , retrieved from where? Basically  you can use external JavaScript function to handle your template:

```
columns.Bound(r => r.IsHavingPromotion).ClientTemplate("#=RenderIsHavingPromotion(data)#");

<script>
    function RenderIsHavingPromotion(model){
          if(model.IsHavingPromotion){
              return '<img src="/promoted.png"/>';
          }else{
              //you other logic
          }
     }
</script>
```

I hope you got the idea.